# t-sql Compare old value with new value before commit update No Trigger

Tags: sql-server, validation, triggers, sql-update, dml

There is a user table `ContractBut(Hmy,Scode,sStaus)`. I want to check value of the `sStaus' column before update to get the old value. If the old value is equal to "Approved" then the update should fail with an error message.
Is this possible without a trigger?

Comment: Of course, you can use stored pocedure

Comment: You don't mean old value - you mean current value before an update is made? Just encapsulate your update with a check for the required sStatus value first.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a trigger?

Comment: @stu You are right the current value before update should be checked against value to be change via update

Comment: @GarethD Tigger may slow the front end application response and triggers do not work well when a bulk update is performed.

Comment: @sergey The update is done via front page written in aspx. I can not change the .aspx page as the application runs on server in a data farm.  However we have full control over the database. Is there any way that stored procedure can be called by a check constraint on contractbut table?